# find html tags for description and map

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Can anyone help me find the right html tags to extract this data from a property website...
https://www.rightmove.co.uk/properties/119854820#/?channel=RES_BUY
I want the url text for the clickable map showing the building location...
[image: clickable map]

The element is shown here....
[image: element]

I have tried the following with beautiful soup...

```
 response = requests.get(url)
`content = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

images = [image['src'] for image in content.findAll('a', {'class': '_1kck3jRw2PGQSOEy3Lihgp'})]

images = [image['src'] for image in content.select('div', {'class': '_38EHcC14J7Q40UwAPp10QP'})]

urls = [urll.get("href") for urll in content.findAll('a', {'class': '_1kck3jRw2PGQSOEy3Lihgp'})]

all_imgs = [img.get('data-src') for img in content.select('img.lazy')]
```

even
`content.findAll('img')` brings up a list without the right link in it.

Are clickable maps treated differently within html?

Answer (score 2):

The data you see on the page is embedded inside `<script>` element in Json form, so [beautifulsoup](/questions/tagged/beautifulsoup) doesn't see it. To get the image URLs you can do:

```py
import json
import re

import requests

url = "https://www.rightmove.co.uk/properties/119854820"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:121.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/121.0"
}

html_text = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
data = re.search(r"window\.PAGE_MODEL = (\{.*\})", html_text).group(1)
data = json.loads(data)

print(data["propertyData"]["staticMapImgUrls"])
```

Prints:

```
{
    "staticMapImgUrlMobile": "https://media.rightmove.co.uk/map/_generate?width=375&height=375&zoomLevel=15&latitude=53.4839&longitude=-2.2451&signature=fCKQqCOrd9TgcTWvD-ug2G9zDt0=",
    "staticMapImgUrlTablet": "https://media.rightmove.co.uk/map/_generate?width=768&height=347&zoomLevel=15&latitude=53.4839&longitude=-2.2451&signature=tLGp-2KqHhRcc4EF4s0iBCGN690=",
    "staticMapImgUrlDesktopSmall": "https://media.rightmove.co.uk/map/_generate?width=580&height=347&zoomLevel=15&latitude=53.4839&longitude=-2.2451&signature=ApOr8Lbx4wCQJspfKyTWZLR0DTM=",
    "staticMapImgUrlDesktopLarge": "https://media.rightmove.co.uk/map/_generate?width=761&height=347&zoomLevel=15&latitude=53.4839&longitude=-2.2451&signature=C2QlMT5ziRNbGMLk0uQBuvz7dqI=",
}
```

Comment: great and what about